# How to add Ellipsis to MenuStrip Item Text

Tags: vb.net, text, menuitem, ellipsis, menustrip

When using a MenuStrip, it's good to have the items and subitems have a certain width and that width should not change. Supposing the width does change to a great length, rather than changing the whole size of the MenuStrip Item to fit the text there should be a way to only display some of the text e.g. Ellipsis.

**Before:**

[image: enter sdescription here]

**After**

[image: After]

Clearly I edited the text of this MenuStrip MenuItem to demonstrate what I mean. Is this possible? if so how can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm guessing that the one entry is dynamically added/updated at runtime?  Otherwise you already have the solution

Comment: If you don't mind saving the original text somewhere else (for example, in the Tag property), you can create a recursive function to find all the items with Text length longer than some defined value and abbreviate those items appropriately.

Comment: Items are dynamically added at runtime

Comment: Use [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you want a constant length and then just append `...`. Make sure you use the long string for a tool-tip or something though, you don't want a handful of file name entries that just say `C:\Windows...`!

Comment: This was my initial plan however I use the menuitem text to launch a program because the menu item is used to store file paths. I get the full path directly from the menu item. If I use substring it wouldn't contain the full path. How can I workaround this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Class Form1

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim strPrograms(1, 4) '(0,*) = EXE name; (1,*) = screen name; (*,n) = Program Index

    strPrograms(0, 0) = "ONE.EXE" : strPrograms(1, 0) = "First"
    strPrograms(0, 1) = "TWO.EXE" : strPrograms(1, 1) = "Second"
    strPrograms(0, 2) = "THREE.EXE" : strPrograms(1, 2) = "Third program description is too long"
    strPrograms(0, 3) = "FOUR.EXE" : strPrograms(1, 3) = "Fourth"
    strPrograms(0, 4) = "FIVE.EXE" : strPrograms(1, 4) = "Fifth"

    Dim intMaxLength As Integer = 10
    Dim tsmParent As ToolStripMenuItem = MenuStrip1.Items.Add("Programs")
    For i As Integer = 0 To strPrograms.GetUpperBound(1)
      Dim strScreenName As String = strPrograms(1, i)
      If strScreenName.Length > intMaxLength Then
        strScreenName = strScreenName.Substring(0, intMaxLength - 1) & "…"
      End If
      Dim tsm As New ToolStripMenuItem(strScreenName)
      tsm.Tag = strPrograms(0, i)
      AddHandler tsm.Click, AddressOf tsm_Click
      tsmParent.DropDownItems.Add(tsm)
    Next i

  End Sub

  Private Sub tsm_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim strEXEName As String = DirectCast(sender, ToolStripMenuItem).Tag
    MsgBox(strEXEName)

  End Sub
End Class
```